# Avoid resend the form if page is refreshed after clicking on a non-ajax command button

Tags: primefaces

I have this simple form example :

```
<h:form id="testForm">
 <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="New" />
</h:form>
```

If I click in the button and then refresh the page. The browser notifies that the form will be sent again. How can I avoid this ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pure Java/JSF implementation for double submit prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285530/pure-java-jsf-implementation-for-double-submit-prevention)

Answer (score 1):

Agree on the duplicate, however there are no examples. One option would be to use

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="New" action="page.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

Comment: There is in a link in the second answer there ;-)